# Query to combine data from 2 tables based on a condition for both the tables in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables. ProfileInfo (ProfileID - PK) and EmployeeRole (EmpID - PK, ProfileID - FK). Both are connected using a ProfileID and both tables have LastUpdatedTimestamp Column. I need to fetch data from both the tables combined, using from and to lastupdated timestamp.

> Sometimes both the tables get updated at the same time and most times
>   only one get updated

. Here is what i have tried but it bring up data which is updated on both tables. Firstly, I tried join but it didn't work as much as i thought it would

```
     select emp.emp_id as EmpId from EmployeeRole emp 
     FULL OUTER JOIN ProfileInfo pi on emp.profile_id = pi.profile_id
     where emp.LST_UPDT_TS between '2017-09-18' and '2017-09-20' and 
     pi.LST_UPDT_TS between '2017-09-18' and '2017-09-20';
```

This brought emp ids that had changes on both the tables alone.

***Table Details:***
**EmployeeRole** Emp_ID PK, Profile_id FK, LST_UPDT_TS TIMESTAMP

**ProfileInfo** Profile_Id PK, Profile_name, LST_UPDT_TS TIMESTAMP

Example: If 2 records of ProfileInfo gets updated and 1 record of EmployeeRole gets updated. I need to get 3 emp_id considering both the records from ProfileInfo is not related to EmployeeRole record. If in case one of the record is related then I have to get 2 emp_id only.

I searched for similar answers for a short period but nothing worked. Please help.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to do?  It's not very clear.  I'd guess you want an OR instead of an AND for your where clause - this would give you results where either table has updated in that time period.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and the desired results?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: You need FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: @Serg I tried that as well it is still showing changes from EmployeeRole table alone.

Comment: Please edit the question and show your FULL OUTER JOIN  version

Comment: @PhilS I need to pick up data from both the tables as in most cases only one of the table gets updated. That's why am using AND instead of OR in where clause.

Comment: Move the WHERE conditions to the JOIN ...ON part

Comment: @wildplasser do you mean something like this  select emp.emp_id as EmpId from EmployeeRole emp 
 FULL OUTER JOIN ProfileInfo pi on emp.profile_id = pi.profile_id and 
  emp.LST_UPDT_TS between '2017-09-18' and '2017-09-20' and 
   pi.LST_UPDT_TS between '2017-09-18' and '2017-09-20';

Comment: Yes, of course I meant that. What else could it mean?

Comment: Besides moving condition as @wildplasser said add needed columns from both tables to SELECT.  You may wish to combine some of them with COALESCE()

Comment: I ran the query and it didn't show the desired result, instead it brought all the details of both the table without timestamp condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked with some little tweeks from the initial query I changed.

```
select emp.emp_id as EmpId from EmployeeRole emp  
 JOIN ProfileInfo pi on emp.profile_id = pi.profile_id and
 ((emp.LST_UPDT_TS between '2017-09-18' and '2017-09-20') or 
 (pi.LST_UPDT_TS between '2017-09-18' and '2017-09-20'));
```

Thanks a lot @Serg and @Phil and @wildplasser

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example, your conditions may vary

```
   SELECT
       -- common data
       COALESCE(emp.profile_id, pi.profile_id) as profile_id
      ,COALESCE(emp.LST_UPDT_TS, pi.LST_UPDT_TS) as LST_UPDT_TS
       -- emp role
      ,emp.emp_id as EmpId
       -- profile
      , pi.Profile_name
  FROM (SELECT * 
        FROM EmployeeRole 
        WHERE LST_UPDT_TS between '2017-09-18' and '2017-09-20') emp 
  FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM  ProfileInfo 
        WHERE LST_UPDT_TS between '2017-09-18' and '2017-09-20') pi
     -- rows matching predicate
      ON emp.profile_id = pi.profile_id
     AND emp.LST_UPDT_TS = pi.LST_UPDT_TS
```

Comment: I tried this one but it is fetching almost all the records from both the tables. I have 288 records in each table with one to one mapping and it is fetching 500 records and it is not considering LST_UPDT_TS somehow.

Comment: I have updated timestamp for 3 records, 1 from EmployeeRole  and 2 from ProfileInfo out of which 1 is related to EmployeeRole result. So i need to get 2 results only.

Comment: @user2632905, Move date constraints into subselects to filter rows first. See updated answer.

Comment: I think its almost there although it is not picking up the corresponding empid from the other table when records of profileInfo alone is changed. But it is producing 3 results, one with proper mapping with emp and profile table, and other 2 are from profile changes with empid as null.